# Signature did not match. String to sign used was r

Tags: azure-storage

Trying to Construct a Shared Access Signature URI for a Blob access in a container

```
BlobHelper BlobHelper = new BlobHelper(StorageAccount, StorageKey);

string signature = "";

string signedstart = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1).ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'");
string signedexpiry = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(2).ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'");

//// SET CONTAINER LEVEL ACCESS POLICY
string accessPolicyXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n" +
                    "<SignedIdentifiers>\n" +
                    "  <SignedIdentifier>\n" +
                    "    <Id>twominutepolicy</Id>\n" +
                    "    <AccessPolicy>\n" +
                    "      <Start>" + signedstart + "</Start>\n" +
                    "      <Expiry>" + signedexpiry + "</Expiry>\n" +
                    "      <Permission>r</Permission>\n" +
                    "    </AccessPolicy>\n" +
                    "  </SignedIdentifier>\n" +
                    "</SignedIdentifiers>\n";


BlobHelper.SetContainerAccessPolicy("xxxxxxx", "container", accessPolicyXml));

string canonicalizedresource = "/xxxxxxx/501362787";


string StringToSign = String.Format("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}\n{4}\n{5}\n{6}\n{7}\n{8}\n{9}\n{10}",
        "r",
        signedstart,
        signedexpiry,
        canonicalizedresource,
        "twominutepolicy",
        "2013-08-15",
        "rscc",
        "rscd",
        "rsce",
        "rscl", 
        "rsct"
        );




using (HMACSHA256 hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(StorageKey)))
{
    Byte[] dataToHmac = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(StringToSign);
    signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha256.ComputeHash(dataToHmac));
}

StringBuilder sasToken = new StringBuilder();

sasToken.Append(BlobHelper.DecodeFrom64(e.Item.ToolTip).ToString().Replace("http","https") + "?");

//signedversion
sasToken.Append("sv=2013-08-15&");

sasToken.Append("sr=b&");
//
sasToken.Append("si=twominutepolicy&");
sasToken.Append("sig=" + signature + "&");
//
sasToken.Append("st=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(signedstart).ToUpper() + "&");
//
sasToken.Append("se=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(signedexpiry).ToUpper() + "&");
//
sasToken.Append("sp=r");

string url = sasToken.ToString();
```

I am getting the following exception below

```
<Error>
    <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
    <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:e424e1ac-fd96-4557-866a-992fc8c41841 Time:2014-05-22T18:46:15.3436786Z</Message>
    <AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. String to sign used was r 2014-05-22T18:45:06Z 2014-05-22T18:48:06Z /xxxxxxx/501362787/State.SearchResults.pdf twominutepolicy 2013-08-15 </AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

Answer (score 1):

rscc, rscd, rsce, rscl, rsct are placeholders for [overridden response headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn140255.aspx). Your sasToken variable does not seem to override response headers, so you should just use empty strings with a new-line character when signing them. Moreover, it looks like your canonicalized resource also does not match the server's resource.

By the way, did you look at [Azure Storage Client Library](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage) to create Shared Access Signature tokens? It provides lots of features and is the official SDK to access Microsoft Azure Storage.

Comment: I modified the "StringToSign" to use   string StringToSign = String.Format("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}\n{4}\n{5}\n{6}\n{7}\n{8}\n{9}\n{10}",
                "r",
                signedstart,
                signedexpiry,
                canonicalizedresource,
                twominutepolicy,
                "2013-08-15",
                "",   
                "",
                "",
                "",
                ""
                );  but still the same issue.

Comment: I had used Azure Storage Client Library , I could successfully generate a SAS token, only the problem happens when I try to use the above for constructing the URL.

Comment: It looks like your canonicalized resource also does not match the server's resource. Could you be missing the "State.SearchResults.pdf" part?

Comment: If you use Azure Storage Client Library to generate a SAS token, you can simply append it to the blob URI.

Comment: Yes, I had tried that , it works fine!. Only when I try above approach it complains the above exception, I tried various combination,  Let me try with canonicalized  resource as you mentioned above.

Comment: As you had mentioned, I have to use the canonical zed resource to the actual file. Its working fine !!!. Thank you !!!.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. I have also updated my answer to mention the canonicalized resource mismatch.